# The SMTP server does not support authentication in Microsoft dynamics 365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

When I'm running the missing weekly timesheet reminder, I'm getting an error.
[image]

[image]

I have set up the SMTP settings and able to test email with authentication.
Test emails are working properly.

Comment: On what version are you testing this? In the error message, there is also a message about a missing `sigprojmissinghourregemail` menu item, which I cannot find on a 10.0.23 environment. Is this a customization? If so, could you [edit] the question and add the code of the customization? Otherwise this looks to be a configuration question, which is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. You can try https://serverfault.com/ or the [Dynamics 365 SCM forum](https://community.dynamics.com/365/supply-chain-management/f/dynamics-365-supply-chain-management-forum)

Comment: The error is because of the SMTP settings, I changed the SMTP email server to Exchange and it's working fine now.